# What will happen to my old xcode when I download new xcode?

Tags: xcode

The question is in the title already. I have an old XCode. Then there is a software update message on my Mac. It said that there is a newer version of XCode. If I download the new XCode, will my old XCode be deleted? Or I will end up with 2 XCodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are upgrading Xcode through the Mac App Store then it will replace your old version of Xcode. However, if you download a beta version then you can have the beta version and the production version on your machine both at the same time.

For example during the iOS 8 beta period, I had the production version of Xcode 5 on my machine and also  Xcode 6 beta (all versions) installed at the same time.

However, either way you really don't need to fret because you can always download the older versions of Xcode through developer.apple.com. Just look in the "Downloads" section and click the "Looking for an older version of Xcode?" link which takes you to: [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)

[image]

Comment: Cheers mate. Just the answer I needed

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you install a GM version of Xcode it will replace your current GM version, and it will be named "Xcode". If you install a beta version, it will install a separate Xcode, with a beta mark appended to the name, eg. "Xcode6-Beta5".